# How to integrate maps in views in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a problem to integrate map in this view:

```js
Ext.define('Sample.view.MainMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    requires: ['Ext.TitleBar','Ext.Video'],
    alias: 'widget.mainmenuview',
    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        items: [
            {
                title: 'Welcome',
                iconCls: 'home',
    
                styleHtmlContent: true,
                scrollable: true,
    
                items: {
                    docked: 'top',
                    xtype: 'titlebar',
                    title: 'Welcome to sencha' ,items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Log Off',
                    itemId: 'logOffButton',
                    align: 'right'
                }
            ]
                },
    
                html: [
                    "Hello to dawini plateforme"
                ].join("")
            },
            {
                title: 'Get Started',
                iconCls: 'action',
    
                items: [
                    {
                        docked: 'top',
                        xtype: 'titlebar',
                        title: 'Getting Started'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'video',
                        url: 'http://av.vimeo.com/64284/137/87347327.mp4?token=1330978144_f9b698fea38cd408d52a2393240c896c',
                        posterUrl: 'http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/261/062/261062119_640.jpg'
                    }
                       ]
            }
        ], listeners: [{
            delegate: '#logOffButton',
            event: 'tap',
            fn: 'onLogOffButtonTap'
        }]
    },onLogOffButtonTap: function () {
        this.fireEvent('onSignOffCommand');
    }
});
```

How can I integrate a map into this view?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try map type in your Sencha component within the Items. Others attribute also can be configured like height, current location etc. And also you need to configure google map api in your Index.html page like,

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>


Example : items: [
            {
                xtype: 'map',
                height: 200,
                useCurrentLocation: true
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://innofied.com/iphone-like-infobubble-with-sencha-touch/) you can find how to include map in Sencha Touch. Though it is focused on infobubble but it is also showing the map integration. Let me know if you have any difficulty implementing this.